# How do I adjust the position attributes of custom Eclipse markers when a file is edited by typing?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, markers

Does Eclipse adjust the position attributes of custom markers when a file is edited?

I have many Eclipse plugins in which I successfully create and delete markers, create quick fixes, and apply edits to the active editor programmatically. When text is inserted or deleted from the buffer all the text in the editor shifts, of course, and Eclipse's markers and my custom markers stay in synch with the text.

The problem is that when the file is edited, whether by regular typing or programmatically by changing the IBuffer, the attributes (e.g. CHAR_START) are not modified - they report the values when the marker was created and first made visible. So when one goes to do a QuickFix on the marker, for example, the reported position is incorrect. (This is an info marker, in CDT, if that matters.)

How are these marker positions supposed to be updated when edits happen?
Is there an Eclipse way to do this, but I need to implement some setting or notification or listener?

One possibility is to implement a ResourceChangeReporter - but it is not triggered for me when text edits happen, just when, for example, a save is invoked. And, if it were, I don't see information about how the file is actually altered.

I suppose I could require that a dirty file be saved before the quick fix is applied, but I still don't see where to obtain information about the file's edits. If I apply the edit programmatically, I know this information, but it does not help when the edit happens by typing.

Answer (score 0):

Marker positions can be updated during editing using an updater declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerUpdaters` extension point and implementing the `IMarkerUpdater` interface.

However there is a default updater `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicMarkerUpdater` which is already active for all markers which should be doing basic position updating for you.

Comment: Thank you. I see the problem is my impatience: the marker updates, at least with BasicMarkerUpdater, happen when a dirty editor is saved - but do not appear to be updated on each edit while the editor is dirty. Is that also what you would expect?

Comment: This depends on when the editor updates the marker annotation model, the basic text editor just does this on save. The Java editor looks like it does it more often.